# Execution of a command in a variable with eval

Tags: bash, variable

I am trying to use grep to color some log files . I wrote a script and a part of it looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
com="GREP_COLOR=\"1;36\" egrep --color=always  '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' $log |less -R"
log="/var/log/syslog"
eval $com
```

The execution was missing $log !

I tried this :

```
#!/bin/bash
com="`GREP_COLOR=\"1;36\" egrep --color=always  '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' $log |less -R`"
log="/var/log/syslog"
eval $com
```

Nothing happened !

Could you see any mistake in my code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Do not use `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Right here it simply could be avoided:

```
function color_log() {
  log=$1
  GREP_COLOR="1;36" egrep --color=always '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' $log | less -R
}

color_log "/var/log/syslog"
```

Comment: Can you summarize the punch line of your link for "Do not use eval"? It is not that obvious.

Comment: There are many cases (and this one is one of them) when `eval` could be simply substituted with something else which helps you to ignore all that redundant checks and thoughts about security issues and safety.

Comment: Your code isn't equivalent to the OP one. You should set the GREP_COLOR variable before the `egrep` command, on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `$` in `$log` in your first script:

```
#!/bin/bash
com="GREP_COLOR=\"1;36\" egrep --color=always  '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' \$log |less -R"
log="/var/log/syslog"
eval $com
```

Edit:

There is indeed no need to use `eval` in this particular case so suggesting an alternative and safer way like ДМИТРИЙ did is definitely preferred. On the other hand, while the design error was to use `eval` in the first place, the coding error which I addressed was not to quote `$log`. While `eval` definitely has a justified bad press because of all vulnerabilities associated with it, it is nevertheless a very powerful instruction that is worth knowing. Carefully written evals can avoid malicious or unexpected code execution.

Comment: Sure, you can get it to work, but this horrible misuse of `eval` should not go uncorrected.

Comment: @Gilles Indeed, I even help the accepted answer to be correct. Updating my own answer to make clear I was addressing the coding error but not the design one.