# Piping to the command substitution of a string containing pipes

Tags: bash, io-redirection, pipe, command-substitution

This works—

```
$ x='grep a'
$ echo ab | $x
ab
```

This doesn't—

```
$ x='grep a | grep b'
$ echo ab | $x
grep: |: No such file or directory
grep: grep: No such file or directory
grep: b: No such file or directory
```

It appears in the latter case, `grep a | grep b` is seen as a single command, *i.e.* `grep a \| grep b`.

How do I get the second example to work without modifying `x`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to run variables that contain code you'll often want to use the command `eval`. This will expand the contents of the variable so that they can be executed.

#### Example

```
$ x='grep a | grep b'
$  echo ab | eval "$x"
ab
```

Using eval is often discourage though, so use caution, see this BashFAQ titled: [Eval command and security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for more examples!

#### References

- [Execution of a command in a variable with eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96859/execution-of-a-command-in-a-variable-with-eval)

Comment: You should double-quote `$x`.

Comment: @barmar good catch will do

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I figured it out after some experimentation—use `alias`—

```
$ x='grep a | grep b'
$ alias y=$x
$ echo ab | y
ab
```

Please do post any other ways to do this—I'd be interested in alternatives.

Comment: When such an alias is run non-interactively, i.e. in a script, you need `shopt -s expand_aliases` before the first use of the alias - interestingly not necessarily before the alias definition.